# css - start new line when we reach width

Tags: css, forms

I have a form with some elemnts ( I get them on runtime). What I need to add to css in order to make the label to start a new line when thw width is full?

example to form:

```
 <form><div><span>
   <label><input type="checkbox"><span >fd1</span></input></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"><span >fd2</span></input></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"><span >fd3</span></input></label>
</span></div></form>
```

Comment: just set a width to the `div`

Comment: What do you mean by “when the width is full”? Browsers wrap the content automatically. If this does not happen, the problem is caused by something in your code that was not disclosed.

Comment: (You are probably solving the wrong problem. For usability, each label/field pair should appear on one line, and you should achieve that using suitable markup, not CSS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for standard css you can use the white-space property (you can play with the values at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_white-space&preval=pre)

for css3 (if you client support it) you can use word-wrap with break-word value